# Sequence representing -1,-1,-1,-1,+1,+1,+1,+1,-1,...

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Main question:**

How can this sequence be represented **without trigonometric functions** ?:

$M_{n} = -1, -1, -1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1, -1, ...$

.

**Second question**:

The ones previous to that seemed to be pretty simple:

$A_{n} = -1, +1, -1, +1, ... = (-1)^{n}$

$B_{n} = -1, -1, +1, +1, ... = (-1)^{n(n+1)/2}$

And you can even represent $B_{n}$ by transforming $A_{n}$.

$C_{n} = (A_{n})/2 + 1/2 = 0, 1, 0, 1, ... $

$B_{n} = C_{n} * A_{n/2} + C_{n+1} * A_{(n+1)/2}$

But Im not very sure how to get a "simple" $B_{n}$ from that formula. Operating you get this:

$2B_{n} = (-1)^{3n/2} + (-1)^{3(n+1)/2} + (-1)^{n/2} + (-1)^{(n+1)/2}$

How can you reach a more compact formula from this ? Maybe using $-1 = e^{i*pi}$ ?

Comment: $M_n$ is not a series. It looks like some sequence. Can you check your definition?

Comment: In maths context, "series" and "sequence" does not mean the same thing.

Comment: $e^{\pi i}$ is essentially a trigonometric function.

Comment: Sometimes I get confused with the traduction to English. Series => $\sum A_{n}$, Sequence => $A_{n} = 1/n$. Right ? I will change the word on the question. Thanks.

Comment: You've gotten lots of correct answers to this amusing puzzle. That said, if I wanted to write this sequence in a book or a paper so that someone would understand it without having to unpack a complicated power of $(-1)$ I would simply write it as you have, and maybe say that the terms were (four positive) (four negative), repeating.

Comment: $$M_n = \begin{cases}
-1,\ \text{for} \ 1\leq n \leq 4,\\
\ \ \ 1 , \ \text{for} \ 5 \leq n \leq 8,\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots
\end{cases}$$

Jokes aside, I definitely agree with @EthanBolker. Simply writing the sequence in words would be far easier for a reader.

Comment: @Ediolot some more definitions at OEIS https://oeis.org/A143621

Comment: Um... is there any reason $a_n = -1$ if $\lceil 4/n \rceil$ is odd and $a_n = 1$ if $\lceil 4/n \rceil$ is even isn't an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one in the same spirit as your $B_n,$ you could write

$$M_n=(-1)^{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/8}$$

Comment: This one seems to be the easiest to me.

Answer (score 1):

How about $M_n = (-1)^{\binom{n+4}{4}}$?

**Edit:** I thought of this formula because it resembles your formula for $B_n$.  Since the exponent $\binom{n+1}{2} = (n+1)n/2$ produced a sequence of two $-1$s followed by two $+1$s, it seemed natural that some variant of $\binom{n}{4}$ would produce the same thing with four $\pm 1$s.  (I think this can be justified by noting that the numerator of $\binom{n+4}{4} = (n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)/24$ includes all four equivalence classes mod $4$.)

Answer (score 1):

How about

$$(-1)^{\large{\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{8}}}$$

Comment: That doesn't start out right: OP wanted -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, etc.  See my answer (posted just before yours).

Comment: Where it starts out depends on the initial value of $n$, which isn't specified in the question.

Comment: True, but his $A_n$ and $B_n$ were written to start at $n=1,$ so I figured that's what he was aiming at.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

$$M_n = (-1)^{\lfloor(n+3)/4\rfloor}, n=1,2,3,...$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2\left(\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor\mod 2\right)-1$$
, where $n$ starts from $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Another one (to avoid $mod$):

$$2\left\lfloor\frac {n+4}8\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac n8\right\rfloor-1$$ 
,where $n$ starts from $0$.